# get the unique number from an array, remove the duplicates completly

Tags: c++

```
int a[5] = {5,2,3,2,4}
```

If i have an array like this, i want to get uniques

Not

> 5,2,3,4

but

> 5,3,4

Any number repeated will be removed.

I have tried using `std::<set>`

```
const size_t len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
std::set<int> s(a, a + len);
```

However, it does not work as it will produce uniques:

> 5,2,3,4

Comment: use hashing . If number is present then not add it and also remove that number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) with [std::multiset::count](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/count), and obtain the elements only when the number of elements with the same key equals to `1` exactly. e.g.

```
int a[5] = {5,2,3,2,4};
const size_t len = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);  
multiset<int> m(a, a + len);

vector<int> v;

copy_if(begin(a), end(a), back_inserter(v), [&m](auto i) { return m.count(i) == 1; });

copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " "));
```

Result:

```
5 3 4
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JHKK74260)

If you can't use lambda, you can write a functor instead, or write the loop directly instead of `copy_if`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    if (m.count(a[i]) == 1) 
        v.push_back(a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Sort the array. Use `std::sort`
- Swap duplicate elements to end. Use `std::unique`

  - Now you have 2 partitions. First partition contains uniques (but includes onces that have duplicates), second contains all the duplicates. `std::unique` returns an iterator to the boundary of the partition (one past the last unique element).
- Result will be `uniques \ duplicates`. Use `std::set_difference` with ranges `[begin,boundary[` and `[boundary, end[`